# Cannot add own custom EFDataAcces Library Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: Reference Manager]

In a web project i would like to add custom library
I right click on dependencies => add reference
It shows my custom library which i did for ef core. But when i click ok button it just does nothing. pretending like nothing happened.

csproj file contents

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>           
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.12"/> </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

Comment: What runtime is the API project targeting, .net 5? Do you get any messages in the Output pane, or errors?

Comment: yes it is targeting .net 5 I don't get any messages or errors. When i tick the library and hit ok button it removes the tick

Comment: Can you post your csproj file contents? What happens if you manually add the project reference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Comment: @gunr2171 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.12" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

These are the csproj file contents. I don't know how to manually add project referance. Reading and learning right now from the article you sent

Comment: @gunr2171 Okay sorry, i am editing my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed after updating nuget packages. Update Swashbuckle and Azure container tools.